# Does the syntax in a Power BI join cause a data refresh?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to make a Power BI report that someone else created run faster and as I'm going through the queries I've noticed some of the merged queries have different syntax and I'm wondering if the different syntax is causing a data refresh to occur during the merge.

Below are 2 different merged queries, but one has the # sign before the table name with the table name in quotes and the other does not. What is the significance of not having the # sign?

It's the #"Org_Roll-Up" vs Account_Groups.

Syntax 1

```
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type9", {"COMPANY"}, #"Org_Roll-Up", {"ORG"}, "Org_Roll-Up", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
```

Syntax 2

```
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"ACCOUNT"}, Account_Groups, {"ACCOUNT"}, "Account_Groups", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
```

I'm trying to get the queries to run once and then send the data to other queries as needed instead of refreshing each time.  I have parallel turned of and background data refresh off.

Answer (score 0):

The way you’ve worded this, I just want to make sure you understand how Power Query does a merge. When you merge query A with query B, Power Query will run query B again for use by query A. It doesn’t pull previously loaded data by query B or table B from the data model (nor does it change table B). It will run the query B again and join it with query A and load the result to table A. So in syntax 1, `#"Org_Roll-Up"` will re-run, and in syntax 2, `Account_Groups` will re-run. Depending on what the query does and how many rows are on the table, you can have quite different performance through small changes. See Chris Webb’s 3 part series here for more ideas: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/05/31/optimising-the-performance-of-power-query-merges-in-power-bi-part-1/